# Asp.net core 3.1 mvc post request model binding for simple types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

When I make a post request to asp.net mvc core 3.1, the controller was able to bind the complex types. how ever for simple (or "primitive") types, e.g. int, string, etc are always null(if I use query string it will pick up).
In asp.net mvc 4 it will pick up no matter what type as long as the name matches. Is this just how core works or I have to make some configuration changes ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding the `[FromBody]` attribute if you are sending those in the body.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#sources